# Get original URL from a reddit URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, reddit

Consider this link:
`https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/6x6iz8/til_princess_diana_on_live_tv_shook_the_hand_of/?ref=share&ref_source=link`

The original like was

`http://www.bbc.com/news/av/magazine-39490507/how-princess-diana-changed-attitudes-to-aids`

Using Javascript, how can I get to the original link from the first link without using Reddit API?

Comment: yeah scrape the page and get the link

Comment: To give you a different perspective or correct your question. The link you provided does refer in any way to the bbc.com link. It just so happens that the page your original link points to contains that link. So the only way would be to scrape the page for that link.

Comment: @Paul: this format is what you get (instead of the original link) when you try to share a post on Reddit (by clicking on the share button)

Comment: @Ari, correct. In essence, when you click share, they are giving you a web page that happens to have a link to the original article. As mentioned, web scraping might be your only option.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about JavaScript that runs in a webpage, you can't. You need to either use the Reddit API, or scrape the Reddit webpage. However, you can't scrape a webpage using JavaScript because of cross-origin security rules, so you have to use the API.

EDIT: Ah, Paul just pointed out that you tagged Node.js; if you're doing this from a server, scraping is possible. Look up "scraping with node.js". After a cursory glance at Google, it looks like most solutions for this involve downloading the Reddit webpage's HTML and then parsing it with a library called cheerio. There's also this thing [scrape-it](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/scrape-it) that looks promising.

Comment: He did tag node.js, so maybe we could assume it's server side and not client side.